# Javascript callback being fired before function is complete (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I have 2 javascript functions, the first being a function which loads ajax content (via another function), and a second which is a callback function. They look like:

```
function createReply(callBack){
    ajaxPage('test.html', 'next-reply');
    callBack();
}

function updateNext(){
    document.getElementById('next-reply').id  = "reply-item";
}

createReply(updateNext);
```

As you can see, I am calling the `createReply()` function and passing it the name of the callback function, in this case `updateNext()`

In the `createReply()` function, I am calling another function which loads content via ajax. When this function is complete, the callback is supposed to be executed. The callback changes the id of the div in which the ajax content is being loaded. This is where the problem is occuring

I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Which is saying that it cannot change the content of the element with the id "*next-reply*" because it doesn't exist, and the reason it doesn't exist is because the callback function changes the id if that element. The intention is to have the callback fire after the ajax content has been loaded (ie; after the `ajaxPage()` function has been executed)

Can anyone see what the problem is? Is there a better way of implementing a callback function in plain javascript?

**PS: no jQuery**

Comment: What is `ajaxPage`?  Can you post the source for that too?  Basically, you'll need to pass `callBack` into `ajaxPage` and call it when the response is returned from the server.

Comment: I thought of that, but I can't change the way the `ajaxPage` function works, it used used widely on the website and I don't want to affect anything else on the site. Surely this defeats the point of a callback function?

Comment: The issue is that your AJAX call happens asynchronously, i.e. `ajaxPage` returns immediately before it *actually* finishes.  If indeed `ajaxPage` doesn't support the concept of a callback event, you need to rethink your design.

Comment: Yeah i think I'm just going to have to bite the bullet and change the way the `ajaxPage` function works. It shouldn't be too bad really, it's just adding an optional callback function to that. I was hoping there would be a "nicer" solution, but oh well. Makes me appreciate jQuery more :)

Comment: That's one of the nice things about JavaScript.  You can just tack an optional parameter to the end and say `if(callback) callback();` and not break your existing code.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll post an official answer too..

Comment: Thanks Mike, marked your answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is due to the fact that AJAX calls happen asynchronously.  The thread that `createReply` runs in continues to run before a response is returned from the server.

You'll need to re-factor `ajaxPage` to accept a reference to `callback`, and call it when the response is ready.  Something like:

```
function createReply(callBack){
    ajaxPage('test.html', 'next-reply', callBack);
}
```

Then, in ajaxPage:

```
function ajaxPage(url, id, callback){
   //Do AJAX stuff

   //When the response is returned:
   if(callback) callback();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yeah I went with that. The main problem I was facing was the `ajaxPage` function was calling a series of other functions, so I had to keep passing the callback function down through the called functions. I got it working, I just don't find it very elegant, was hoping there was a neater solution.

Comment: Yea that's what scoping is for.  If all those *other functions* were within the `ajaxPage()` function scope, you wouldn't need to keep passing it around.  But glad you got things working!

Answer (score 0):

Right now you callback is executed right after the ajaxPage function. By right after I mean you do not wait for ajaxPage to return success. It is fired right after the ajax call goes out. It is very likely that it is not completed before your callback is fired.