# Detecting content loaded on ajax div

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the ajaxpage function provided by the code on Dynamic Drive (http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm).

I am trying to make the original page that sent the ajax content request to the div to detect once the div is loaded.

This is what I have tried:

- A lot of research points to this
  functionality in jQuery. I do not wish to use jQuery at all in this
  project.
- Including script in the loaded content. This doesn't work
  and I believe it's due to limitations of this functionality.
- I have
  tried monitoring different states of the div, however nothing seems
  to change.

All I really need is a way to call a function on the main page once the div content is loaded.

Comment: No one wants to go to Dynamic Drive an reverse-engineer their code to answer your question. Please post YOUR relevant code as part of YOUR question.

Comment: Was only using that link to demonstrate what I am working with.

Comment: I am still unsure why the comments on this question were deleted when the first comment from Diodeus was kept in. It is condescending and doesn't help at all.. It's also wrong... there are many helpful people on this site that point others in the right direction. alejandro being one of them who helped me a lot and gave me a place to start. I am going to focus more on these sorts of people rather than those that are here to put others down.

Comment: @SystemX17 If you feel the comment is obsolete or not constructive, you can flag it as such. It's generally frowned upon to demonstrate by providing a link to a 3rd party site if you didn't also include enough code directly in the question to recreate the problem. Since that problem still isn't fixed, i see that comment as still relevant.

Comment: "you didn't also include enough code directly in the question to recreate the problem" so alejandro who did find it had enough information to help me is psychic? No, he just understood what I needed help with and helped me. Other comments on this question were removed from that user who commented after he kept just taking a dig at me. I wasn't asking for someone to provide me with code, and from the solution - it was that I didn't understand the concept - making it very difficult for me to describe and document my exact issue. If someone has enough information to help me how is this wrong?

Comment: I guess it's a case for some of if you don't post something exactly how I wanted it (even though there is enough information provided to solve the problem) then you should just get off Stack Overflow. This just makes people put less effort in when asking questions as they are probably just going to get flamed even if the information is there but not presented specifically in a way that some people want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify ajaxpage function , add another parameter for a callback function, call your function within onreadystatechange. but I recommend you to use jQuery instead.

UPDATE:

Here's what I did. I added new a parameter called *callback* to your function *ajaxpage* , when you fire the ajax event onreadystatechange if I we get a true value from *loadpage* we excecute the *callback* and to identify which page or content was I'm adding the *page_request* and *containerid* arguments. Now you can add that callback function to your `ajaxpage` function in this case I did it with the function called `myCallbackFunction`.

I don't recommend you this approach there a better ways and best practices, if you're learning avoid this it seems out of date.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Ajax Rotating Includes Script</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Dynamic Ajax Content- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

var loadedobjects = ""
var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname

    function ajaxpage(url, containerid, callback) {
        var page_request = false
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
            page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // if IE
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        } else
            return false
        page_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (loadpage(page_request, containerid)) {
                if (callback)
                    callback(page_request, containerid);
            }
        }
        page_request.open('GET', url, true)
        page_request.send(null)
    }

    function loadpage(page_request, containerid) {
        if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1)) {
            document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = page_request.responseText
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function loadobjs() {
        if (!document.getElementById)
            return
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var file = arguments[i]
            var fileref = ""
            if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file) == -1) { //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
                if (file.indexOf(".js") != -1) { //If object is a js file
                    fileref = document.createElement('script')
                    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                    fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
                } else if (file.indexOf(".css") != -1) { //If object is a css file
                    fileref = document.createElement("link")
                    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                    fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
                }
            }
            if (fileref != "") {
                document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
                loadedobjects += file + " " //Remember this object as being already added to page
            }
        }
    }

    function myCallbackFunction(page_request,containerid) {
        // Do your stuff here 
        console.log("page_request", page_request);
        console.log("container id", containerid);
    }

</script>

<style type="text/css">
#leftcolumn{
float:left;
width:150px;
height: 400px;
border: 3px solid black;
padding: 5px;
padding-left: 8px;

}

#leftcolumn a{
padding: 3px 1px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#leftcolumn a:hover{
background-color: #FFFF80;
}

#rightcolumn{
float:left;
width:550px;
min-height: 400px;
border: 3px solid black;
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 5px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
}

* html #rightcolumn{ /*IE only style*/
height: 400px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="leftcolumn">
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/external.htm', 'rightcolumn', myCallbackFunction);">Porsche Page</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/external2.htm', 'rightcolumn', myCallbackFunction);">Ferrari Page</a>
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/external3.htm', 'rightcolumn',myCallbackFunction);">Aston Martin Page</a>

<div style="margin-top: 2em">Load CSS & JS files</div>
<a href="javascript:loadobjs('ajaxfiles/style.css', 'ajaxfiles/tooltip.js');">Load "style.css" and "tooltip.js"</a>

</div>

<div id="rightcolumn"><h3>Choose a page to load.</h3></div>
<div style="clear: left; margin-bottom: 1em"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am looking into adding a function as a parameter in the ajaxpage function to perform a callback. I will look into how other javascript functions utilise callbacks for some direction. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Searching for callbacks I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867806/javascript-callback-being-fired-before-function-is-complete-no-jquery. Seems like this will really help me. Thanks again.

Comment: From pointing me in the right direction I found http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-69201.html which has the modified code I was seeking. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cheers for updating that. I was typing my comment as you were updating it I believe. Went with the code you supplied :)

Comment: The problem with this solution  dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-69201.html  is that they passed the callback function 2 times ! which I consider unnecessary .. maybe the loadpage function should be within the callback .. and ajaxpage should be just an ajaxrequest as any other frameworks does.